# jquery mobile databox plugin how to set the time

Tags: jquery-mobile, datebox

I am using the following to set the date of the datebox plugin

```
<input data-id="ti_datebox" type="date" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"useInline":true, "noSetButton":true}'>

$ti_datebox.trigger('datebox', {'method':'set', 'value': theDateStr, 'date':theDate})
```

However, I can't set the time with the same code.

```
<input data-id="ti_datebox" type="date" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"useInline":true, "noSetButton":true, "mode": "timebox"}'>

$ti_datebox.trigger('datebox', {'method':'set', 'value': theDateStr, 'date':theDate});
```

Ideally, I'd like to set the time based on some string values and not an actual date object.
Is this possible? If not, how can I set the time?
Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's actually easier than you are making it - DateBox has a 'set' method as well, that takes a string as a value (in the same format as it outputs as it happens).  There is no need to send it a date object as well - it will handle creating that.

So, you would:

```
// For 12hr clock
$('datebox element').trigger('datebox', {'method':'set', 'value':'08:00 AM'});

// For 24hr clock
$('datebox element').trigger('datebox', {'method':'set', 'value':'08:00'});
```

A working example is here:

http://jsfiddle.net/jtsage/AbVqh/1/

fwiw, if you for some reason need more control, all the set method actually does is change the value in the input box, and call the "refresh" method - which re-reads the input.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. The input box is set but not the value on the time picker. It still shows the current time. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for this:

```
$('input[data-id="ti_datebox"]').trigger('datebox', {'method':'set','value':"08:00"});
```

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Should have read this a bit closer the first time, it is indeed correct.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the example for the demo site

- http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox/demos/time/
- http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox/demos/api/events.html

**Time Default**

```
<label for="mydate">Some Time</label>

<input name="mydate" id="mydate" type="date" data-role="datebox"
   data-options='{"mode": "timebox"}'>
```

**12 Hour Clock Mode**

```
<label for="mydate">Some Time</label>

<input name="mydate" id="mydate" type="date" data-role="datebox"
   data-options='{"mode": "timebox", "timeFormatOverride": 12}'>
```

Comment: Yep looked at those. My problem is I can't set the time pro-grammatically. Cheers though.