# JQuery Mobile Datebox set using date object

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, datebox

In the API [here](http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox/demos/api/events.html) it says:

> Trigger to set specified date
>
> {'method'} === set
>
> {'value'} === value to place in input
>
> {'date'} === the date object being used

I want to set the datebox using my Date object variable "nowTime". But it just does not work. [In other posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9278479/jquery-mobile-databox-plugin-how-to-set-the-time/9283284#9283284) people usually set the datebox by value (which is a string) which is not quite neat at all. Is there any problem with my code? Or is it the datebox's bug?

My Code:

```
nowTime = new Date();
nowTime.setHours(8);
nowTime.setMinutes(50);
alert(nowTime.toLocaleString());
    
$("#departureTime").trigger('datebox', {'method':'set', 'date':nowTime}).trigger('datebox', {'method':'doset'});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me if you do the following:

```
$("#Date1").datebox('setTheDate', nowTime).trigger('datebox', {'method':'doset'});
```

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/zU7G9/)**

Comment: Right. In API public functions:

`$('element').datebox('setTheDate', <date>);
Set the current date object`

So what does method "set" with "date" parameter do?

Comment: I agree with you that from the API docs what you had should work. Perhaps you can contact the developer and ask.